# How to find the pronounciation of symbols you don't know about?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Like I see this symbol, I think it's a big J but it could be some greek letter or something.

[image]

Comment: `\mathcal J` gives $\mathcal J$.

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a useful tool for figuring out what symbols are.

Comment: Its just a capital English letter J, except scripted in a calligraphic style.  Its meant to set it apart from other instances of J's. We do this when we run out of letters and subscripts. It could have a specific meaning in some contexts but that all depends on the context. As for how its pronounced, I couldnt tell you; that too would depend on its contextual usage. I would default to just calling it a J.

Comment: @Sandejo Im bookmarking that. Thanks.